# Redirecting with Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to Azure SSO.  I currently have an internal web forms application that I've added Azure SSO to using Owin.  I can login and all of that is working correctly for the inital login.  The issue that I am having is that whenever I lose my session or try to directly link to a page it takes me from my current page and send me back to my default page after login.

Is there a way around this?